# Attic access in closet- reconfigure options (Canada)

Tags: code-compliance, attic, accessibility

I have a narrow bathroom and this is because the builtin closet of the adjacent room takes space from the bathroom.

I am planning to remove the walls that separate the bathroom from the closet in order to make the bathroom bigger.

My problem is that the access to the attic is done via a hole that was cut in the ceiling within the closet at its top side. Any access to the attic requires me to remove the content and the shelves of the closet. The attic is not used for any purpose, just insulation up there.

Are there any code restrictions or practical reasons that would stop me from doing the above?  (The attic access would end up in the bathroom).

I live in Ontario, Canada, so I am asking about that code

Comment: So your question is "can I plug up that hole" or is the question "is it ok to have that hole in my bathroom"?

Comment: the second, ..is it OK to have the hole in my bathroom? (I am thinking about humidity mainly

Comment: To the best of my knowledge I don't think there is anything in the IBC that prevents this. The only thing I am aware of is sealing the conditioned space from unconditioned space. (A gasket seal). http://www.batticdoor.com/BatticDoorNewAtticAccessBuildingCodes.pdf